# Converting Matlab code to C++ with Matlab Coder - Cell problem

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm trying to convert a function to C++ in Matlab Coder.. There is a cell variable and while building mex it gives an error.

```
     R=cell(1,n);
for i=1:wi
        for j=1:hi
            if(cin(i,j)>0)
                     k=cin(i,j);
                    for x=i-2*rx+1:i+2*rx-1
                        for y=j-2*ry+1:j+2*ry-1
                                if(x>=1 && y>=1 && x<=wi && y<=hi)
                                    R{k}=[R{k}, (x-1)*wi+y];
                            end
                        end
                    end
            end
         end
end
```

It gives error on R{k}=[R{k}, (x-1)*wi+y]; part

'Attempt to access an element that was not defined before use.'

Anybody can help me about this?

Comment: this is not c++, is your issue related to c++ at all? if not, take the tag out so its not confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For code generation, you have to define (i.e. assign) all cell array elements prior to their use. Here `R{k}` is used prior to being assigned. Namely, the `R{k}` on the RHS of that assignment reads that element prior to it having been assigned.

If you intend the elements to be empty matrices, `[]`, then you can declare `R` like:

```matlab
% Cells should be varsize to grow them later on
coder.varsize('R{:}');

% Initialize all cells to empty
R = repmat({[]}, 1, n);

for i=1:wi
        for j=1:hi
            if(cin(i,j)>0)
                     k=cin(i,j);
                    for x=i-2*rx+1:i+2*rx-1
                        for y=j-2*ry+1:j+2*ry-1
                                if(x>=1 && y>=1 && x<=wi && y<=hi)
                                    R{k}=[R{k}, (x-1)*wi+y];
                            end
                        end
                    end
            end
         end
end
```

More details in the MATLAB Coder doc:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/cell-array-restrictions-for-code-generation.html